# Red5 streaming video breaks the seek-bar in my video player

Tags: video-streaming, red5, flvplayback

I have a simple video player (build with the FLVPlayback component in Actionscript 3). If I stream RTMP video through Red5 I lose the ability to control the video, although it does play. The seek bar is just forever 'revolving' and stop doesn't work. I also get an error message about an SSL certificate from localhost:localdomain - which I assume is connected. I'm not trying to run anything through https that I know about. I am using the Red5 oflademo application.

If I use the same video player with Flash Media Server, everything is fine.
Thanks for any clues
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Being a Red5 developer, I have never heard of such a thing happening. It is extremely odd that an HTTPS or RTMPS request would be made while seeking unless you were already connected using SSL. I have heard that the FLVPlayback component was "flaky" when used with Red5, but this is a new thing; were you on an HTTPS page?